How can Christians avoid antinatalist implications of 1 Corinthians 7?
1 Cor 7:8 (ESV):

"To the unmarried and the widows I say that it is good for them to remain single, as I am"

1 Cor 7:32-34 (ESV):

"... The unmarried man is anxious about the things of the Lord, how to please the Lord. But the married man is anxious about worldly things, how to please his wife, and his interests are divided. And the unmarried or betrothed woman is anxious about the things of the Lord, how to be holy in body and spirit. But the married woman is anxious about worldly things, how to please her husband."

1 Cor 7:38 (ESV):

"So then he who marries his betrothed does well, and he who refrains from marriage will do even better"

Here is the antinatalist implication of these verses. If we follow Paul's advice and stay single and childless, then humanity would go extinct (because nobody will replenish the population). But the doctrine that argues for human extinction (antinatalism) is widely regarded by Christians to be a false one. The implication that the "ideal" scenario is the one where humans die out is an incredibly repugnant one.
So my question is, how can Christians interpret 1 Corinthians 7 to avoid all of these 3 implications below?

it is better for humanity to go extinct
it is better to be single
it is better to be childless

Edit: My question is different from the proposed duplicate, because the duplicate asks a general philosophical question, while my post asks a specific question about the interpretation specific Bible verses by St. Paul (1 Corinthians 7:8; 1 Corinthians 7:32-34 and 1 Corinthians 7:38).

Who says those interpretations are necessarily problematic?

Every Christian who is against antinatalism (and there is a lot of them).

That's your claim I guess, but that's not necessarily a broadly held or taught Christian ideal.

I don't have polling data, because this issue is very niche, but I feel like it would be quite dishonest to suggest that Christians who hold that it is better for humanity to go extinct are not a minority.

I would actually argue that Christians who are more concerned about the human species going extinct simply than spiritual things like Paul is talking about should be in the minority at least as far as doctrinal schools.

One piece of evidence to support that is that an average Christian birth rate is 2.7 children per woman, while average atheist birth rate is 1.6 children per woman. It would certainly be surprising if the majority of Christians held antinatalist views and were reproducing at above-average rates.

This question is similar to: Would God allow all of humanity to be celibate?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Thank you for notifying me! I have edited the post to clarify it's originality.

If this were an apologetics question, it might be on topic, but it's really about a Christian response to a hypothetical implication from a particular reading of a few parts of the Bible.  As such, this is more always going to be a philosophical question unless you can edit it to include a particular faith tradition (which would probably invalidate all the answers)


For I would that all men were even as I myself. But every man hath his proper gift of God, one after this manner, and another after that. - 1 Corinthians 7:7

In this verse Paul acknowledges that marriage and childbearing is the absolute norm (Genesis 1:28), albeit fraught with difficulty due to sin and temptation from within and without.
The married person, by very definition, has the split allegiance of caring for the things of the Lord and also caring for the needs of the spouse.  Paul is not suggesting that caring for one's spouse is less than good; in fact He states the opposite in much of the passage.
Verse 7 (For I would that all men) is not a command, it is a linguistic device.  He is saying, "I wish that everyone could have unfettered devotion to the Lord, like I do."
The next word is "but".  Paul knows that his "wish" is not something to be corporately aimed at here and now.  Cessation of marriage and being given in marriage is a higher goal for another paradigm (Matthew 22:30).
Here and now the ability to remain unmarried (that is to say free of concupiscence) and serve the Lord alone is a gift given by God.  This is Paul's point:  Operate in accordance with your giftedness.  If you are not gifted by God to remain single, then marriage is not only lawful but preferable.
Far from advocating antinatalism Paul is exhorting God's people to faithfully live according to their particular calling and giftedness.  The rest of the chapter unpacks this principle starting at verse 17:

But as God hath distributed to every man, as the Lord hath called every one, so let him walk. And so ordain I in all churches. - 1 Corinthians 7:17


I like your answer a lot, although I do have one question remaining. You mentioned that remaining unmarried is a gift by God. Is getting married and starting a family also a gift in a similar manner? If so, are these 2 gifts (singleness and marriage) equal or is singleness like gold medal and marriage like silver medal?

@SuperFlash  Just to say that the site looks for one question at a time. Additional questions should be posted as fresh questions, though the link to this one could be included, for reference.  Once you've given enough time for as many answers to be submitted as you feel necessary, you select the one that you deem to be most helpful and give it the green tick. But if no answer 'deserves' that, just leave it at that. Hope this helps.

@SuperFlash I would say that marrying and having kids is the norm by creation and that singleness is a giftedness given for the sake of the Gospel.

That makes sense to me. Your answer is probably the best one here

Paul is not arguing for antinatalism in the secular/modern sense. To advance such a claim would require reading some verses to the exclusion of others and stretching the implication of those verses.
After saying it is good for a man not to touch a woman (verse 1), he outlines norms for marriage. Specifically, that it is better to marry than to fornicate:

But for fear of fornication, let every man have his own wife, and let every woman have her own husband.  Let the husband render the debt to his wife, and the wife also in like manner to the husband.  The wife hath not power of her own body, but the husband. And in like manner the husband also hath not power of his own body, but the wife.  Defraud not one another, except, perhaps, by consent, for a time, that you may give yourselves to prayer; and return together again, lest Satan tempt you for your incontinency.
-- I Corinthians 7:2-5

If Paul were simply arguing it is better to remain single or childless, he would be unlikely to provide moral guidance for marriages.
Further, while he states a wish that all men be as he is (that is unmarried), he says "every one hath his proper gift from God"; hence, remaining unmarried or marrying is in relation to a gift from God to maintain that state.
The key difference between what Paul is talking about and what secular antinatalists mean comes in verse 32: "He that is without a wife, is solicitous for the things that belong to the Lord, how he may please God." He is not saying to avoid marriage and children simply or for selfish reasons, but so that one may aim more to please God by not having to provide for the needs of others ("how he may please his wife").
Paul is not making a claim that it is better for humanity to go extinct (Although he is also not making a claim here that it is better for humanity to procreate -- if only because such an argument would have been unnecessary in that time). He is saying it is better to remain celibate or in virginity, but only to please the Lord.
In other words, Paul is saying it is preferable to remain unmarried, but not all can do so yet all should do what the Lord has granted them to be able to do.

"Paul is not making a claim that it is better for humanity to go extinct". But that's the logical conclusion (the implication if you will) of his words. If he is saying it is better to remain celibate or in virginity, but only to please the Lord, then the implication of people following his "better" scenario is humans going extinct.

Only if everyone does, which he does not argue for.

The conclusion of "If we follow Paul's advice and stay single and childless, then Christians would go extinct" doesn't sound much better to me.

The point you keep overlooking is why. Antinatalism aims at intentional extinction because reproduction is viewed as immoral (in some form). Paul is not saying anything bad about reproduction. He is talking about aiming at God. If you can't see that difference, nothing I can say will help.

Antinatalist relates to the belief that it is morally wrong or unjustifiable to have children.
Paul is not saying it is morally wrong or unjustifiable to have children. Christian values on marriage and bringing up children would exclude unmarried women and widows to procreate. That is not being an antinatalist. A Christian man who wants to dedicate his life to serving the Lord is not an antinatalist.
I have never heard of any so-called "doctrine" of antinatalism that argues for human extinction.
Such a "doctrine" (if it exists) goes contrary to God's instruction to the first man and the first woman to have children and "fill the earth".
There is no implication anywhere in Scripture that the "ideal" scenario is the one where humans die out.
Please provide proof that this "doctrine" exists.

If I say, "he who refrains from marriage will do even better" and I also say that reproduction outside of marriage is a great evil, then I have to foresee that in my "ideal world" humans go extinct. And if I still say that it is better to refrain from marriage, then that means that even taking into the account the consequences of my "ideal world", I still condone it
That's akin to analysing the statement "It's better for everyone to jump off the cliff". Either you don't see how that results in death or you do see how that results in death and still say it's better despite it

If Paul is saying that celibacy is like the gold medal and marriage is like a silver medal, then the gold medal outcome is the human extinction. That's just the consequence of people staying celibate


If we follow Paul's advice and stay single and childless, then humanity would go extinct

This is a flawed conclusion, so there is no implication of antinatalism.
It incorrectly equates "we" and "humanity":

By "we", Paul means all true Christians, the "elect", those who follow Christ's example.
The vast majority of "humanity" has always been non-Christian.

At 8 billion and climbing, the danger of extinction is from overpopulation.

That's fair, but the conclusion of "If we follow Paul's advice and stay single and childless, then Christians would go extinct" doesn't sound much better to me.

St. John Chrysostom addresses this in his commentary on 1 Corinthians 7, De virginitate.
In ch. 15 "Marriage does not increase the human race.", he argues:

And today our race is not increased by the authority of marriage but by the word of our Lord, who said at the beginning: "Be fertile and multiply; fill the earth." [Gen. 1:28] How did marriage help Abraham in the procreation of children? After participating in it for so many years, did he not finally cry out: "Master, what will you give me? Am I to die childless?" [Gen. 15:2] […] For marriage will not be able to produce many men if God is unwilling, nor will virginity destroy their number if he wishes there to be many of them.

